# XNA game keeps shutting down because the phone 'sleeps'

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone

Is there a way to programatically stop the phone from sleeping? Since my game doesn't involve touching the screen, it won't stay active more than a few seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would probably do it:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

Note the warning [in the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.useridledetectionmode%28VS.92%29.aspx), however, as this is a bit battery-unfriendly.